# Ways to iterate and append a date calculation a set number of times in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

Let's say I have a sheet with this dataset:

```
Start Date      Number of Days   
3/1/2019        2
```

From this input set, I want to make the following transformation:

```
Date
3/1/2019
3/2/2019
3/3/2019
```

A new date, incremented by one day, is added to the column "Date" for the total amount (listed under Number of Days).

Here's another dataset:

```
Start Date      Number of Weeks
3/1/2019        2
```

In this case, the resulting array should be:

```
Date
3/1/2019
3/8/2019
3/15/2019
```

Comment: Welcome. What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

```
Start Date      Number of Days   
3/1/2019        2
```

Assuming 3/1/2019 is cell A2 use the following formula `=arrayformula(sequence(B2+1,1,0)+A2)`
and the result will be:

```
3/1/2019
3/2/2019
3/3/2019
```

If you want to do weeks a simple modification like this will give you the exact result you asked for:

```
=arrayformula(sequence(B2+1,1,0,7)+A2)
```

[SEQUENCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244)